# Android View Pager - setOffscreenPageLimit prevent loading until tapped

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using a View Pager with 4 tabs in my app. Each tab hits an API and loads in data.

I'm using `setOffscreenPageLimit(4)`in order to prevent the data reloading every time a tab is swiped and made visible. This is all working.

However them problem is currently when the app opens it fires all 4 tabs initially. The behavior I'm after is only load in the given tabs data once its been tapped.

Below is essentially what my Tab Adapter looks like:

```
public class TabsFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"};

    Fragment1 f1;
    Fragment2 f2;
    Fragment3 f3;
    Fragment4 f4;

    public TabsFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        f1 = Fragment1.getInstance();
        f2 = Fragment2.getInstance();
        f3 = Fragment3.getInstance();
        f4 = Fragment4.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0)
        {
            return f1;
        }
        else if(position == 1)
        {
            return f2;
        }
        else if(position == 2)
        {
            return f3;
        }
        else if(position == 3)
        {
            return f4;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

What can I do be doing differently to achieve my desired behavior?

**EDIT**

Basic fragment list example:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment  {

    public static Fragment1 getInstance() {
        return new Fragment1();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // get data and load list/adapter
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your fragments code?

Comment: Thanks for your help... it's now posted. Very simplifed

Comment: cant see where are your fragments loading data

Comment: look at onActivityCreated. That's where I do the call to the API and on response fill adapater

Comment: what about putting the code to fill the adapter in onResume instead in onActivityCreated. this way creating all fragments doesn-t hurt your performance. loading is done, when the fragment becomes visible

Comment: it looks like onResume gets called as well initially. I only want the call to happen when the tab is tapped and not before

Comment: Why dont you use an interface to notify the fragment when you want it to load.

Comment: Hey nanoc... how might something like that look? Thanks!